# Rotating a Long Table with RevTeX

Tags: revtex, sidewaystable

I'm looking to rotate a rather large table in my document. The table is now large enough that it will span multiple pages. Previously, I was using `sidewaystable` to rotate it, as it was the only solution I found that worked. However, `sidewaystable` doesn't appear to work with multipage tables.

When similar questions have been asked before, the solution was to use `pdflscape`. Unfortunately, I have to use AASTeX, which is based on REVTeX, and `pdflscape` doesn't work well with REVTeX, so that is out of the question too.

Is there a way to get `sidewaystable` to work with multipage tables, or is there a very similar package that does?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE...Can you post your `MWE` for further checking...

Comment: Possibly the answer is `No`, you can not break the rotating tables by auto...